# How can I select same attribute without using class or id?

Tags: html, css

Consider the code given below

```
<body>
  <div>
    <a href="http://www.google.com">Google</a>
    <a href="http://www.gmail.com">Gmail</a>
    <a href="http://www.fb.com">fb</a> 
  </div>
</body>
```

If I want to select  `<a>` tags without using any class and and want to give different properties to them,is there any way?

Comment: Yes there are lots of ways. Are you trying to reference them using CSS or Javascript?

Comment: Great.From css.Please tell me a few.

Comment: @learner Your comments sound like you are taking a technical interview :)

Comment: @GopalAggarwal No bro. I am not. I am just a student. Sorry for the language.

Comment: @learner We are all students here. Meant no offense on your language :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
a { } // all the links
a + a { } // second link 
a + a + a { } // third link
```

or

```
a:first-child { } // first link 
a:last-child { } // last link
```

Comment: You told me a lot of ways. Can you tell me a few more.

Answer (score 1):

With CSS you can check the `href` attribute like this:

```
a[href^="http://www.g"] {
    color: red;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9dep7/)

`^=` means "starts with this".
`$=` means "ending with this".
`*=` means "contains this".

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you could do:

```
document.body.children[0].children[0] // Google link
document.body.children[0].children[1] // Gmail link
document.body.children[0].children[2] // FB link
```

However this is a really bad idea because as soon as you change your HTML structure you will have to rewrite all of your code.

Comment: This is best idea: Use IDs.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to do it with CSS, I'd say:

```
 a:nth-of-type(2){color:black;} // Select the second
 a:fist-child { color:red;} // Select the first
 a:last-child { color:blue;} // Select the last
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always declare CSS inside of the tags themselves, like this:

```
<a href="http://iodelta.com" style="color:#0F0; font-weight:bold; display:block;">Link Here</a>
```

Comment: I wanted to do it by 
CSS not html.

Comment: This IS css... so what do you want?

Answer (score -1):

use jquery  (http://www.jquery.com)
it's the famous  JavaScript library to manipulate with the DOM
ex:

`$("a")`      select all the link .
`$("a:contains['Gmail']")`   select the link with text gmail

Comment: No need to use jQuery just for this task